# Dateformat not working in Firefox browser

Tags: sapui5

I am getting a JSON response from my REST containing three properties with associated date formats as below:

createdAt: 2017-01-10T06:43:16.076Z (Saved in the backend using @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP ): Comming from rest call

fromDate: 2017-01-16Z (Saved using @Temporal(TemporalType.Date): Input field with datepicker to capture date entered by user

toDate: 2017-01-17Z (Saved using @Temporal(TemporalType.Date): Input field with datepicker to capture date entered by user

In my XMLView I am using a formatter class to show the above three dates as
10-Jan-2017, 16-Jan-2017 and 17-Jan-2017.

```
Formater class:

sap.ui.define([

    "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat"
], function(constants, DateFormat) {
    "use strict";

    var _parse = function(v) {
        var oDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
            pattern: "dd-MMM-YYYY"
        });
        var oDateTimeFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
            pattern: "dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"
        });
        return oDateFormat.parse(v) || oDateTimeFormat.parse(v) || new Date(v);
    };

    var _getFormattedDateTime = function(v, patt) {
        if (!v) {
            return v;
        }

        var oDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
            pattern: patt
        });
        return oDateFormat.format(_parse(v));
    };

Return {
Date: function(v) {
            return _getFormattedDateTime(v, constants.DateFormat);
        },

DateTime: function(v) {
            return _getFormattedDateTime(v, constants.DateTimeFormat);
        },
}
```

And i am calling the same in the xml view for the view element as:

```
for createdAt field:

<Text text="{path:'list>embHeaderData/createdAt', formatter:'.formatter.Date'}" tooltip="{path:'list>embHeader/createdAt', formatter:'.formatter.DateTime'}"/>


for fromDate field:

<Text text="{path:'list> embProcessData /fromDate', formatter:'.formatter.Date'}" tooltip="{path:'list> embProcessData /fromDate', formatter:'.formatter.DateTime'}"/>


for toDate field:

<Text text="{path:'list> embProcessData /toDate', formatter:'.formatter.Date'}" tooltip="{path:'list>embProcessData/toDate', formatter:'.formatter.DateTime'}"/>
```

The three date formats are working fine in chrome but fromDate and toDate are blank in firefox when i see the same xml view.

Can you please help me to correct this issue in the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing own formatters you can use the standard data types and their rich configuration features:

```
<Text 
    text="{path : 'list>embHeaderData/createdAt', type 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { pattern: 'd-MMM-Y', source : { pattern : 'yyyy-MM-ddTH:m:s.SZ' }, UTC : true }}"
    tooltip="{ path : 'list>embHeaderData/createdAt', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: { pattern: 'd-MMM-Y HH:mm:ss', source : { pattern : 'yyyy-MM-ddTH:m:s.SZ' }, UTC : true }}"/>

<Text 
    text="{path : 'list>embProcessData/fromDate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { pattern: 'd-MMM-Y', source : { pattern : 'yyyy-MM-ddZ' }, UTC : true }}"
    tooltip="{path : 'embProcessData/fromDate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: { pattern: 'd-MMM-Y HH:mm:ss', source : { pattern : 'yyyy-MM-ddZ' }, UTC : true }}"/>

<Text 
    text="{path : 'list>embProcessData/toDate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { pattern: 'd-MMM-Y', source : { pattern : 'yyyy-MM-ddZ' }, UTC : true }}"
    tooltip="{path : 'embProcessData/toDate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: { pattern: 'd-MMM-Y HH:mm:ss', source : { pattern : 'yyyy-MM-ddZ' }, UTC : true }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please remove the white spaces in your binding path for fromDate and toDate.
2. Please use a date format like this (assuming all times UTC):

   ```
   var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
       pattern: "yyyy-MM-ddZ",
       UTC: true
   });
   var oDateFormatter = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
       style: "medium",
       UTC: true
   });
   // example:
   oDateFormatter.format(oDateFormat.parse("2017-01-17Z"), true);
   ```

   to parse toDate and fromDate.
   The error is because

   ```
   new Date("2017-01-17Z")
   ```

   does not work in Firefox but it does in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I removed it but still it's working only in chrome and not in firefox.

Comment: Hi Sebastian,using the above format the dates are appearing in all browsers but now fromDate is: 2017-01-16+0530 but i need it like  16-Jan-2017.How do i do this?

Comment: I changed the answer assuming your times are UTC; but I don´t know if it´s UTC or local time zone in your case and what you would like to display